# Support JobScheduler's JobService when minSdkVersion is pre-lollipop

Tags: android, service, android-jobscheduler

My minSdk is 19 and my targetSdk is 27 
I am trying to use JobScheduler for BOOT_COMPLETED for Build.Version >= 21 devices and traditional method for pre-lollipop devices. 
But I am getting calls require 21 current minSdk is 19.

[image]

What annotations do I need to use, I tried TargetApi(21) but it ONLY targets lollipop and not higher.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Evernote's Android-Job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job). It provides similar functionality for lower API levels.

Or [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) just came out. I believe it is currently in beta. It's library is similar to Evernote's and will also use either AlarmManager or Firebase JobDispatcher for API levels <21.
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager

Comment: WorkManager seems prefect for my case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Jobscheduler was introduced in 5.0. For versions lower than 5.0, use Firebase JobDispatcher. Refer this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling) for more details.

> Firebase JobDispatcher is an open-source library that provides an API
>   similar to JobScheduler in the Android platform. Firebase
>   JobDispatcher serves as a JobScheduler-compatibility layer for apps
>   targeting versions of Android lower than 5.0 (API level 21).

Comment: Thank you I will look into that. But for now I am going with the traditional method.

Comment: What do you mean traditional method?